# vue-router 4 '/:pathMatch(.*)*' not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

hello guys I want to ask about vue-router.
when I use vue 2 if there is a page that doesn't match, I use **path: '*'** to go to my page404 but in vue 3 it's been replaced with **'/:pathMatch(.*)*'** after i tried it the warning in console disappeared but i just got a blank page and it doesn't point to my page404. did i miss something? I'm newbie with vue 3

here is the version I'm using:

1. vue: ^3.0.0
2. vue-router: ^4.0.0-0

and this is my index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouterView } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
   {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/login',
      component: RouterView,
      children: [{
        path: '/login',
        component: () => import('@/views/login/Login.vue'),
      }]
   },
   {
      path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
      component: () => import('@/views/page404/Page404.vue')
   }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write it like this

```
{
    path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
    redirect: "/404"
},
{
    path: "/404",
    name: "404",
    component: () => import("@/views/page404/Page404.vue")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `/:pathMatch(.*)` instead.

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: NotFound,
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      component: AboutPage,
    },
    {
      path: "/blogs",
      component: BlogPage,
    },
    {
      path: "/:pathMatch(.*)",
      component: NotFound,
    },
    {
      path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
      component: NotFound,
    },
  ],
});
```

Difference between `/:pathMatch(.*)` and `/:pathMatch(.*)*` is their prefix route pattern.

For expample -

In `/foo/:pathMatch(.*)`, it means that it accept that prefixed with '/foo' `/foo/any-miss-name`.But when you try `foo/any-miss-name/any-miss-name2`, `any-miss-name2`'s prefix is `any-miss-name` and not `/foo`.That is why, it will not match and not working.

In `/foo/:pathMatch(.*)*`,it means that it accept any prefixed pattern (no need to start with '/foo').So whenever you try `/foo/any-miss-name/any-miss-name2/any-miss-name(n)/`,it will match and will work perfectly.